# Non blocking client socket in C ( LINUX)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

I am working on a requirement which checks the availability of network connection on servers(if network is stable or not).
I am having a function, which finds the servers registered at a central server. I am adding a layer of network check over this function by extracting the URL and port number of the servers and trying to connect to them by behaving like a simple TCP client. If the return value is greater than 0, then it means that the network is working fine; if -1, then the network is broken.

With such a check, I sometimes observe variable inconsistent times when the network of a server is down. The reason for such behavior is also justified in the link : [Inconsistent time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982762/connect-functionality-of-socket-communication/66987962#66987962).

To counter this, I have an idea of having a non blocking client socket, which tries to connect to the server. With this approach, what I observe is, each time, when the client connects to the server, the return value of the connect() function is -1 always.

I plan to monitor to connect() function for maximum of 5 seconds, and if it fails, it should send a negative response.

What I want to achieve: If server is available, connect =0, then break it, else wait for 2seconds, if still not responsive, then conclude as timeout.

```
printf("--Checking for network connectivity--\n");
        for(size_t i = 0; i < serverOnNetworkSize; i++) {
           UA_ServerOnNetwork *server = &serverOnNetwork[i];
           A[i] = (char *)UA_malloc(server->discoveryUrl.length+1);
           memcpy(A[i],server->discoveryUrl.data,server->discoveryUrl.length);
           A[i][server->discoveryUrl.length] = 0;
           int length = strlen(A[i]);
          
          //discovery URLs are of the form : opc.tcp://hostname:port
          
          //new addition to extract port
            B[i] = A[i] + 10;
          //printf("Hostname: %s\n", B[i]);
            char *p = strrchr(B[i], ':');
            int port = strtoul(p+1, NULL, 10);
          //printf("%d\n",port);
            B[i][length-5]='\0';
          //printf("Hostname: %s\n", B[i]);
         

         
           //removing the port
           A[i][length-5]='\0';
           //without initial tcp binding
           C[i] = A[i] + 10;
          //printf("Hostname: %s\n", C[i]);

          // FIND IP OF THAT HOST
           if(i!=0){
            char ip_address[50];

            find_ip_address(C[i],ip_address);  
            socketCommunication(ip_address,C[i],port);
       }
}
          printf("--Checks done!--\n");
```

Global Functions:

```
int find_ip_address(char *hostname, char *ip_address)
{
      struct hostent *host_name;
      struct in_addr **ipaddress;
      int count;
      if((host_name = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
      {
            herror("\nIP Address Not Found\n");
            return 1;
      }
      else
      {
            ipaddress = (struct in_addr **) host_name->h_addr_list;
            for(count = 0; ipaddress[count] != NULL; count++)
            {
                  strcpy(ip_address, inet_ntoa(*ipaddress[count]));
                  return 0;
            }
      }
      return 1;
}
int ret;
void socketCommunication(char *ip_address,char *hostname, int port){
     int clientSocket,ret;
    struct  sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];
 
    
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK,0);
    if(clientSocket<0){
        printf("Error in connection \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //printf("Client socket is created\n");

    memset(&serverAddr,'\0',sizeof(serverAddr));

    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_address);
    //monitoring for 5 seconds
    for(int i =0; i<=5;i++){
        
        ret = connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr));
        //printf("%d ", ret);
    
        sleep(1);
    }
    if(ret<0){
        printf("\nLOOKS LIKE NETWORK CONNECTION HAS FAILED. HAVE A LOOK AT    THE NETWORK CONNECTIVITY at host : %s\n",hostname);
        printf("\n----Updated Status Information----:\n");
        printf("Discovery URL : opc.tcp://%s:%d\n",hostname,port);
        printf("Status:CONNECTON TIMED OUT\n");
        printf("\n");
   }
```

Output:
Inspite of the servers being active, it shows a failed response

```
LOOKS LIKE NETWORK CONNECTION HAS FAILED. HAVE A LOOK AT THE NETWORK CONNECTIVITY at host : o755-gksr

----Updated Status Information----:
Discovery URL : opc.tcp://o755-gksr:4840
Status:CONNECTON TIMED OUT

--Checks done!--
Time measured: 6 seconds.
```

Technically, is it possible to have a nonblocking client, just to have a connect()function to a blocking server? The server are always listening to connections from client.

If it can be achieved, any guidance to this approach here?

Regards,
Rakshan

Comment: Instead of showing code parts that are not related to your problem you should create a [mre]. In your example case this would be the function `socketCommunication` with a simple `main` function that calls `socketCommunication` with hard-coded values. I already suggested this in your previous question. The code should compile without errors and ideally without warnings and when run it should reproduce your problem .

Comment: yes, i agree.  I am facing segmentation faults in such codes. I am trying to fix them

Answer (score 5):

You should not be repeating the `connect` operation. Just issue `connect` once. If it fails with `EINPROGRESS`, you just need to wait for the `connect` to succeed. You don't need to issue another `connect`.

You can check if the connection is successful several ways. The easiest is probably just to use `getpeername`. If you have a peer, the socket is connected. You can also use `select` or `poll` to check if the socket is writable.

If the connection failed and you want to get the error reason, just try to `read` one byte. It will fail and give you the error code. You can also use `getsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ...)`.

See [this famous post](https://cr.yp.to/docs/connect.html) for less information.

Comment: since the approach is nonblocking, the connect operation error prints to  be : Operation is progress. It just does not wait for any response from the server, and thus, always results in failure.Actually, my aim is to only check for network availability, Peername would be got after the connect operation right? that is only if it succeeds

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad If `connect` returns operation in progress, you need to wait. You can use `select` or `poll` if you want to wait for the socket to become writable or you can just wait some time. Then you can use `getpeername` to see if the socket connected successfully.

Comment: @ David Schwartz, so basically, there cannot be any mechanism, which can achieve a scenario wherein, if a connect does not respond in 2 or 5 seconds, it is a failure right? I mean from a coding point of view?

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad If you want to call `connect`, wait 2 seconds, then check if the connection completed, you can consider it a failure if it didn't complete if you want. Just understand that the connection might have succeeded had you just waited a bit longer.

Comment: yes I understand.. actually I have done the blocking way, it took about 18 seconds. I want to finish the connect module check sooner.. may be 5 seconds at max. The part I'm unclear is the coding here.. connect() will not wait, for 2 seconds..